# EF, Abstraction and Generic Extensions what is the Compiler doing here?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have an extension method for a common interface used on my entities

```
public static IQueryable<T> IsEdited<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
        where T : IAuditData
{
    return from o in source
           where o.CreatedOn != o.UpdatedOn
           select o;
}
```

when I call it

```
var editedUsers = dataContext.Users.IsEdited();
```

I get

> Unable to cast the type 'IUserData' to type
>   'IAuditData'. LINQ to Entities only
>   supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types

IUserData is an interface too, I use it to abstract the DbContext's DbSet properties

```
IQueryable<IUserData> Users { get { ... } }
```

but if I add a class constraint, all is well

```
public static IQueryable<T> IsEdited<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
        where T : class, IAuditData
{
    return from o in source
           where o.CreatedOn != o.UpdatedOn
           select o;
}
```

which makes me happy. 
But what it is that the compiler is doing to tell EF that T is a reference type?

Comment: The expression tree passed to EF is different. without the class constraint the where clause entities are cast to the interface e.g. (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])((Antix.Data.Entity.Interface.IAuditData)$o).CreatedOn != ((Antix.Data.Entity.Interface.IAuditData)$o).UpdatedOn

Comment: your comment is more helpful than the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct` type are [not supported by EF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading.aspx). If you do not constraint the parameter as a class it can also be a struct.

Comment: I was wondering what the compiler was doing really, but that does explain why ef throws the error - thanks